# Does distant metamagic feat when applied to storm sphere apply to the 60' range of the bonus action lightning bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic

If I use distant metamagic when casting storm sphere would this only double the range I can drop the sphere from 150' to 300'? Or would this also apply to the bonus action lightning bolt from the center of the storm sphere making it got from 60' to 120'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Rules-as-written: It would only impact the range for casting the sphere.

Distant Spell metamagic reads (emphasis mine):

> **When you Cast a Spell** that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.
>
> When you Cast a Spell that has a range of touch, you can spend 1 sorcery point to make the range of the spell 30 feet.

The metamagic only applies when you cast the spell. The lightning bolt is a subsequent effect of the spell **after it is cast**.

Accordingly, **only the 150' range of Storm Sphere is doubled to 300'.**

Comment: You might also mention that the “range” of a spell is a very specific element of the spell description, defined prior to the block of text we usually refer to as the spell description.

Comment: This specifies when you spend the sorcery point, not when the metamagic has effect.  "When I buy a car, I can spend more money on a faster car" doesn't mean the car is only faster when I buy it; it means I spend the money *when I buy it*.  The following parts of the sentence aren't also restricted to "when I buy it".  Can you provide evidence outside of this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

### RAW, it only impacts the range the storm sphere can be cast out to, not the lightning bolt range or the storm sphere diameter.

The *range* of a spell is a defined games rules term.  Here you can see it on DnDbeyond.

[image]

While it is written range/area, range is distinct from area.

The lightning bolt does have a range - 60' - but it's not a *range* range, it's not in the range section of the spell description, it is just an effect of the spell.

[image]

**However**, it would be a very reasonable houserule to allow Distant Spell to create a storm sphere that can shoot lightning bolts further.  Distant spell is a weak metamagic (rarely taken), storm sphere is not the best 4th level spell by a significant margin, and the storm sphere lightning bolt being able to shoot further will likely only come up rarely - most D&D 5e combats occur in relatively small areas, rarely is 60' in any direction from the center of an effect not enough to cover the entire extent of the combat from start to finish.  Being able to occasionally shoot at a fleeing or long-range attacking enemy at the cost of expending metamagic points is not broken or even 'okay' - it's kinda bad, honestly, but if the player wants long range shooty lightning bolts and is willing to pay the price for them then letting them have that is probably by far the best choice to make.

Comment: Can you cite where "range" is defined as that value?  (formatting in a table isn't a definition, which is what you have cited)

Comment: A quote from https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range (or even https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell ) might do it.

Answer (score -2):

Reading spells in 5e is a bit of work if you run into corner cases like this.

[Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) states:

> Each spell description begins with a block of information, including the spell's name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. The rest of a spell entry describes the spell's effect.

A naive reading of this would mean that "**Range**" refers *only* to the entry at the start of the spell.  In this case, the sorcery metamagic would double this value -- the center of the storm sphere would be up to 300' away, and nothing else would change.

But in 5e, things aren't quite that simple.  For example, fireball.  Fireball's target in the top description is a point within range, from which a fireball explodes.  Then the *spell effect* goes on to talk about the fireball *targeting* creatures in the explosion, doing damage to them.

This matters, because there are other spells that interact with *target*s of spells - forbidding you from *target*ing a specific creature with a spell, for example.

(This has been backed up as intentional by the designers of D&D.  Fireball targets not just a point, but also the creatures it burns.)

So the **Target** entry at the top of a spell is one way for a spell to target something, *but not the only way*.  Targets of a spell are not limited to only those described in the **Target** entry.

In short, the spell's effect (the body of the spell) can augment or change the meaning of the introductory block of information.

This doesn't mean the naive reading is wrong.  It just means we aren't allowed to stop with the naive reading!  Stopping with the naive reading will often give the right answer, and it should be your first step.  Once you have done it, you should ponder "well, is there anything else it could have missed?"

So for Storm Sphere, we can then read [the part of the effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/storm-sphere) where the secondary attacks are described:

> [...] cause a bolt of lightning to leap from the center of the sphere toward one creature you choose within 60 feet of the center. Make a ranged spell attack.

So we have a ranged spell attack coming from the center of the sphere going 60 feet towards one creature you choose.

We then look at the spell [attack roll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls) rules:

> Most spells that require attack rolls involve ranged attacks. Remember that you have disadvantage on a ranged attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature that can see you and that isn't incapacitated.

Here, it reminds you that a ranged spell attack is a ranged attack.  So we should look into the [ranged attack rules:](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#RangedAttacks)

> Many spells also involve making a ranged attack.

which reinforces that we are indeed looking in the right section.  The [Range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Range) subsection states:

> You can make ranged attacks only against targets within a specified range.

which means that 60' value above?  **It is a range** on the ranged spell attack the spell storm sphere allows you to take with a bonus action.

And, as it is a range on the storm sphere spell, distant spell doubles it.  Even though it was not listed on the initial block of the spell description, the body of the spell can extend that initial description.

Comment: You are reading into the *formatting* of DND Beyond that is not present in the official sourcebooks. Notably, *there is no target or area entry in the front matter of a spell description*. In the official publications of spells, targets and areas of effect are defined exclusively in the text description, *not* in an entry dedicated to defining those things at the top of the spell description. Ergo, any answer which attempts to leverage those things from the digital DDB description is automatically suspect, and here, I think it leads to you a conclusion inconsistent with the official rules.